# Proxy error 502 , run node js app on apache2 server

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, proxy, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to run a Node.js app on an Apache server listening port 80
here is my Virtualhost file :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName mikus

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /node http://localhost:8000/
ProxyPassReverse /node  http://localhost:8000/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined </VirtualHost>
```

Here is my app.js file :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.get('/node', function(req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Welcome apache');
});

app.listen(8000, 'localhost');
```

And when im trying to run the app at 'localhost/node' or ip_adress/node, I have a 502 Proxy error : The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /node.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: localhost

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Enable proxy in `app.js`:

```
app.enable('trust proxy');
```

And fix the uri for the valid route in node.js:

```
ProxyPass /node http://localhost:8000/node
ProxyPassReverse /node  http://localhost:8000/node
```

Comment: Hi Lucas, thanks for the fast answer, unfortunately I still have the same error ..

Comment: Yes it's working if I run 'node app.js' and go to the route localhost:8000/node.

Comment: Sorry, in Apache I don't know what is doing. Node.js works very well with Nginx, because Nginx it's the best than Apache to serve static files. And config reverse proxy in Nginx works well too. Maybe be of your interest search and try it.

Answer (score 0):

localhost may be a ipv6 address , try 127.0.0.1 insteed